Where does user login in oauth 2.0 flow
I'm having difficulty understanding how authentication and OAuth authorization work together, particularly in the Authorization Code flow. I've looked up several resources, but the information seems inconsistent.
My initial understanding was that the authorization endpoint would take the user's username and password, then return an authorization code. However, in the examples I've found, the authorization endpoint appears to expect an access token instead.
For reference, here are a couple of example sources:
https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-amplify-identity-broker/
Based on this, I think the flow works like this:
The user is redirected from the client app to the OAuth /authorize endpoint.
If there's no access token, the user is redirected to the /login endpoint.
The user enters their username and password, and an access token is returned.
The user is then redirected back to the /authorize endpoint, this time with the access token.
The /authorize endpoint then returns an authorization code, which the client redirects to a third-party custom URI.
Can someone please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, if this understanding is correct, my question is: why doesn't the /authorize endpoint handle the authentication directly and return the authorization code?

This is needed when auth server and the server with the content aren't run by the same company. For example, when you log in with google / okta / apple / etc, those run the auth server, and the web site you log into needs to grant you access.

In the authorization code flow, you first get an authorization code which is then exchanged for a token.
This shows an example of that flow:
https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow
So the question really is why doesn't it return the token directly instead of a code that must be exchanged for a token?  That is addressed in this question:
oAuth2.0: Why need "authorization-code" and only then the token?  This mechanism allows the token to never be sent to a browser, which increases security.
